# Secure SSMTP Files

Tags: 16.04, server, security, ssmtp

I've set up SSMTP as my server's mailing agent. I noticed that I had to insert my server mail host information and my password is viewable in plain text. Is there an effective way to secure that file so the server still works but no one except me can see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed `ssmtp` using `sudo apt install ssmtp` this is already the case. The configuration is in `/etc/ssmtp/`, which is not accessible for normal users:

```
[~]$ cd /etc/ssmtp/
-bash: cd: /etc/ssmtp/: Permission denied
[~]$ sudo ls -la /etc/ssmtp/
total 24
drwxr-x---   2 root mail  4096 Dec 31 18:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 159 root root 12288 Dec 31 18:53 ..
-rw-r-----   1 root mail   200 Apr 13  2016 revaliases
-rw-r-----   1 root mail   589 Dec 31 18:53 ssmtp.conf
```

The configuration files are owned by root and group of `mail`, which means that users that are member of the group `mail` can read them. No normal users should be member of `mail`, but the user *running ssmtpd* should be a member of this group.

So by default the files is accessible only to root and the user running the piece of software.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just have a question on permissions. My understanding is the root group gives access to the root console and subsequent files. Sudo is just access to run sudo commands. If some of my users have sudo access, could they get in, or would they need to be in root or mail groups?

Comment: Root is the superuser. `sudo` is a tool for running commands as another user - by default `sudo`. Any user that can run a command as root has *complete* access to the machine, and there's *nothing* you can do to hide this from such users. If you don't trust them, don't give them sudo access.